# Find edge orientations of strongly unclosed edges in unsharp point clouds

Tags: matlab, image-processing, orientation, edge-detection, point-clouds

I want to extract orientations of strongly unclosed edges from a binary image. The image consists of blobs, blob rows and unsharp edges as shown below. In the end every pixel should be assigned to an information about the orientation of the edge. If the existence of an edge is not confident the point should not be assigned. Parameters of a line or a whole curve would be fine but are not necessarily needed.  The edges to be found are marked as red curves:

[image: Red edges]

I tried a lot and I hope for some hints in regarding to methods I could use.

Hough Transformation with Lines: Because of the existence of curves as well as point clouds it is difficult to extract the relevant extreme values of the HT.

Hough Transformation with Ellipses: Same disadvantages as ‘HT with Lines’. Plus the amount of curves and point arrangements to be detected exceeds the limits of a fast process.

Local masks: Go from pixel to pixel and estimate the orientation with the help of a directed mask  (Example: Count all white pixels for every considered direction and make a decision in regarding to the highest number of found pixels). By using this method the view on bigger structures like whole blob rows is obscured. It is easy to see that this method will fail in clouds an edge goes through.

I guess an estimation of the orientation by considering local and global information is the only way. I need to know something about the connectivity of these blobs before making local decisions.
Btw, I am using MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [image moments](http://www.mukimuki.fr/flashblog/2009/05/20/magic-moments/)? you can calculate the angle, mayor axis, and eccentricity of each single blob and define parameters to merge interceeding ones.

You can use the `regionprops()` or start from scratch with this code I just so happend to have here:

```
function M=ImMoment(Image,ii,jj)

    ImSize=size(Image);

    M=0;
    for k=1:ImSize(1);
        for l=1:ImSize(2);

             M=M+k^ii*l^jj*Image(k,l);

        end
    end

end
```

and for the covariance matrix:

```
function [Matrix,Centroid,Angle,Len,Wid,Eccentricity]=CovMat(Image)

 Centroid=[ImMoment(Image,0,1)/ImMoment(Image,0,0),...
     ImMoment(Image,1,0)/ImMoment(Image,0,0)];

 Miu20=ImMoment(Image,0,2)/ImMoment(Image,0,0)-Centroid(1)^2;
 Miu02=ImMoment(Image,2,0)/ImMoment(Image,0,0)-Centroid(2)^2;
 Miu11=ImMoment(Image,1,1)/ImMoment(Image,0,0)-Centroid(1)*Centroid(2);

 Matrix=[Miu20,Miu11
         Miu11,Miu02];

 Lambda1=(Miu20+Miu02)/2+sqrt(4*Miu11^2+(Miu20-Miu02)^2)/2;
 Lambda2=(Miu20+Miu02)/2-sqrt(4*Miu11^2+(Miu20-Miu02)^2)/2;

 Angle=1/2*atand(2*Miu11/(Miu20-Miu02));
 Len=4*sqrt(max(Lambda1,Lambda2));
 Wid=4*sqrt(min(Lambda1,Lambda2));

 Eccentricity=sqrt(1-Lambda2/Lambda1);

end
```

Play a little bit around with that, I'm pretty sure that should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will consider this in regarding to get the orientation of elongated edge parts.

Unfortunately these blobs could appear to be very circular and so I wouldn’t find any hint about the orientation. I guess an estimation of the orientation by considering local and global information is the only way. I need to know something about the connectivity of these blobs before making local decisions.